# Which architecture is more scalable

Tags: wcf, azure, scale

I'm developing a application for *Windows **azure** cloud service*.

The general description for the application is quite simple: a front end on MVC 4, a middle tier for processing front-end processing requests and a SQL Azure/Blob backend...

I did not started to write code so far, and before that i would like to get some feedback on the which of the following scenario would models is more scalable and possibly why. If you think that theres a N'th option that i did not considered please expose it!

Just to be clear single tier app is out of question.

> **Scenario 1:**
>   Front-End consumes a WCF service on middle tier that does all the processing.
>
> **Scenario 2:**
>   Front-End consumes a WCF service on middle tier that queues up that request on a SB and waits. "Tier 3" consumes the message and processes it, also queueing the answer for WCF Service to respond...
>
> **Scenario 3:**
>   Front-End queues a message and loops waiting for response message. "Tier 3" consumes the message, processes it and re-queue it for Front-End to stop waiting...

Basically all the questions resume to "How well WCF scales-out horizontaly?"...

Comment: Have you thought of using SignalR? Thus you will not have to keep WCF Service on hold until get response. Secondly, you can send the response directly to the client. Last but not lease, SignalR has a ServiceBus binding [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Azure-service-bus) With SignalR Front and Back tier are talking kind-of-directly, and you don't have to deal with the actual implementation of long-polling or websockets or what-so-ever.

Comment: @astaykov no i did not contemplated signalR! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most scalable solution is the one that you ruled out — a single tier web app with no shared state that can have as many nodes as you like. There is nothing more *scalable* than *n* web servers behind a load balancer and *m* distributed database nodes. Since you've ruled out the most scalable architecture, you are asking the wrong question, because you are probably not after scalability. Perhaps you are looking at some other architectural principle such as availability.

Why do we separate out functionality across multiple services? There are many reasons. Asynchronous processing allows better availability (by writing to a queue and not being concerned about failures). It also allows us to manage bottlenecks, such as the database. We also break our application up into services in order to ease development, deployment. So it may be availability, maintainability, security, performance, deployability, cost, usability, testability, compliance, or something else that you are looking for. You kinda need to answer that question for yourself before grabbing the scalability hammer. I wrote [CALM](https://github.com/projectcalm/Azure-EN) specifically to help ask, and answer, these difficult questions.

Back to the specifics of your question. The *de facto* asynchronous processing pattern that is generally scalable (if that is what you really need) on Windows Azure does not have WCF in it. Is there a specific reason for WCF? It had better be a good one, because WCF and Service Bus, if not needed, introduces unnecessary complexity. On Windows Azure we implement asynchronous processing with Web Roles (that host the MVC app), that place messages on Windows Azure Queues, these are processed by worker roles. If you need the client (browser) to know about the result, you can hand roll a CQRS pattern, or use SignalR, as other people have mentioned. I would seriously look at taking out WCF.

In terms of your scenarios:

> **Scenario 0:**
>   Stateless web servers do all processing and communicate directly with distributed database node. This is the most scalable, but has other disadvantages.
>
> **Scenario 4:**
>   Front end places message on Azure queue and returns result to client. Worker role processes message and puts result *somewhere* (table storage or blob). Browser Javascript polls for result data and presents it to client when 'done'. This is CQRS-ish. (dunnry's answer)
>
> **Scenario 5:**
>   Front end places message on Azure queue and returns result to client. Worker role processes message and sends result to client via SignalR. (jgauffin's answer)

I would prefer Scenario 5

Answer (score 1):

Messaging is always the most scalable solution since you can configure any number of workers to consume the messages and process them.

The switch to asynchronous handling is however not trivial if you still want the UI to act synchronously. You typcially switch to task based UI where there is no immidiate feedback to the users (or faked feedback).

I've blogged about how you can use queries, domain events and commands to scale out: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/10/writing-decoupled-and-scalable-applications-2/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what the front-end requirements are.  Is this a website that expects a response with data?  Typically, a message queuing pattern will be more scalable (but not faster) as you then have many options to process the requests.  However, once you go that path, it is harder to get direct synchronous-like feedback to the user without a few tricks (SignalR might be a choice here).

For what it is worth, I tend to use the CQRS pattern in the cloud as it scales well for what I need.  I have to deal with the fact that the command is processed async and the user does not get a synchronous response.  The UI has to deal with it then.  We use a command processing table with status.  The web (our client in this case) has to poll that table to figure out when a command has been completed in order to know when to try and display any results to the client.  For us, this is a worthy trade-off to get the scale we are looking for (and other benefits of CQRS).